# fixing the rotated columns such that they'll take less space

Tags: tables, multirow

I have a camera ready deadline today. How can I fix the following table such that columns gets fixed and also use less space? It is CVPR 2019 conference.

```
\newcommand{\rb}[1]{\rotatebox{80}{#1}}%
\begin{table*}[ht]
    % \centering
    \begin{tabular}{rrrc|ccccccccc}
    Dataset & \multicolumn{1}{p{0.1cm}}{\centering \# \\objects}  &  \multicolumn{1}{p{0.1cm}}{\centering \# \\frames} & Description & 
    \rb{depth} & \rb{stereo} & \rb{\multicolumn{1}{p{0.5cm}}{\centering 3D \\ pose}}  &
   \rb{\multicolumn{1}{p{0.5cm}}{\centering full \\ rotation}}  & \rb{occlusion} & \rb{\multicolumn{1}{p{0.5cm}}{\centering extreme \\ lighting}}  & 
    \rb{\multicolumn{1}{p{0.5cm}}{\centering segment \\ ation}}  & \rb{\multicolumn{1}{p{0.5cm}}{\centering bbox \\ coords}} & \rb{\multicolumn{1}{p{0.5cm}}{\centering flying \\ distractors}} \\
    \hline

    UW RGB~\cite{lai2011large} & 300 & 250k & various & 
    \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark \\

    LINEMOD~\cite{hinterstoisser2012model} & 15 & 18k & various & 
    \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark \\

    Pascal3D+~\cite{xiang2014beyond} & 12 & 30k & various & 
    \xmark & \xmark & \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark \\

   % Brachman et al.~\cite{brachmann2014learning} & 20 & 10k & various & 
  %  \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark \\

    Rutgers APC~\cite{rennie2016dataset} & 24 & 10k & warehouse & 
    \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark \\

    T-LESS~\cite{hodan2017t} & 30 & 10k & industrial & 
    \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark \\

    YCB Video~\cite{xiang2017posecnn} & 21 & 134k & household & 
    \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark \\

    Falling Things~\cite{tremblay2018falling} & 21 & 60k & household & 
    \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark \\

    SIDOD & 21 & 144k & household & 
    \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark \\
         & 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Object pose and detection datasets with at least 10,000 frames.} %TODO: finish caption.}
    \label{tab:comparison}
\end{table*}
```

currently it looks like the following (like there is lots of space between 3D pose and the green checkmark. Also, # objects and # frames are stuck to each other.

[image]

Comment: Can you please make your code snippet be compilable? How are the definitions of `\cmark` and `\xmark`? Why do you not rotate the first four headings too? Use for example `\rb{\# objects}` instead `\#\\objects` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see, if you liked the following solution:

[image]

- for table environment is used `tabularx`
- for heads are used macros `\thead` and `\rothead` from the package`makecell`
- rotated head are orthogonal (for better spacing)

  ```
  \documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
  \usepackage{rotating}
  %    \usepackage{subfig}
  \usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
  \usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
  \newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
  \newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%

  \usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
  \renewcommand\theadfont{\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont}
  \usepackage{siunitx}

  \begin{document}
      \begin{table*}[ht]
      \small
      \settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont distracters}
      \renewcommand\rotheadgape{}
       \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
      \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ @{}
                   r
                   S[table-format=3.0]
                   S[table-format=3.0,
                     table-space-text-post={k}]<{\,k}
                   l |
                 *{9}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
                                @{} }
      \hline
  \thead[b]{Dataset}
  & {\thead[b]{\# \\objects}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead[b]{\# \\frames}}
                                                          & \thead[b]Description
  & \rothead{depth}            & \rothead{stereo}         & \rothead{3D \\ pose}
  & \rothead{full\\ rotation}  & \rothead{occlusion}      & \rothead{extreme\\ lighting}
  & \rothead{segment\\ action} & \rothead{bbox\\ coords}  & \rothead{flying\\ distracters} \\
      \hline
  UW RGB~\cite{lai2011large}
      & 300 & 250 & various
          & \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark  \\

  LINEMOD~\cite{hinterstoisser2012model}
      & 15 &  18 & various
          & \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark  \\
  Pascal3D+~\cite{xiang2014beyond}
      & 12 & 30  & various
          & \xmark & \xmark & \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark  \\
  Rutgers APC~\cite{rennie2016dataset}
      & 24 &  10 & warehouse
          & \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark  \\
  T-LESS~\cite{hodan2017t}
      & 30 &  10 & industrial
          & \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark  \\
  YCB Video~\cite{xiang2017posecnn}
      & 21 & 134  & household
          & \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark  \\

  Falling Things~\cite{tremblay2018falling}
      & 21 & 60  & household
          & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark  \\
  SIDOD
      & 21 & 144  & household
          & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark
  ```